# generating additional rows in two table at once after selecting dropdown value in HTML+js

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a dummy data using HTML and js.
So the condition is:

1. I have 2 tables, first table id is `staticTable`, second is `dynamicTable`
2. also dropdown with id `dropdownVal` value from 1 to 5
3. `staticTable` has 3 rows.
4. `dynamicTable` is generated based on `dropdownVal` value times 3 rows from `staticTable`

staticTable and dynamicTable (before generated by js) code:

```
   <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3" style="padding: 15px;">
    <label for="dropdownVal">Total Row</label>
    <select id="dropdownVal" name="dropdownVal" class="form-control form-select mb-3">
      <option value="0" selected>-- Please select --</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5" style="padding: 2px; font-size: 8pt;">
      <h4>Table A</h4>
      <div class="table-responsive">
        <table id=staticTable>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Profile Pic</th>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>ID</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Pic 1</td>
              <td>Andy</td>
              <td>001</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Pic 2</td>
              <td>Michael</td>
              <td>003</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Pic 7</td>
              <td>Rachel</td>
              <td>019</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-7" style="padding: 2px; font-size: 8pt;">
      <h4>Table B</h4>
      <div class="table-responsive">
        <table id=dynamicTable>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Profile Pic</th>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>ID</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="3" style="text-align: center;">-- No Data --</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Question**
Q: How to add empty row in `staticTable` for each generated loop row in `dynamicTable` using javascript?
I want the table to look like this, assuming I select value **3** in dropdown:
[image: generated rows in static and dynamic table]

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find out how to create and append elements:

```
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_nodes.asp
```

You will have to figure out how to insert at the right place. Get started here:

```
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/coll_table_rows.asp
```